# Tracking Custom events in Facebook Analytics Dashboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

I am firing Custom events from my application via Facebook Analytics. Although we can view the default triggered events in Events tab in FB Analytics dashboard, I'm unable to view my customised ones.

Can anyone help me with the Custom events viewing in FB Analytics Events dashboard?

Here is my code:

```
private AppEventsLogger logger; 
logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(mContext); 
Bundle parameters = new Bundle(); 
parameters.putString("Time","2:30 pm"); 
parameters.putString("Date","22/11/2016"); 
logger.logEvent("Parent Profile",parameters);
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you're using to fire custom events?

Comment: private AppEventsLogger logger; 
logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(mContext); 
Bundle parameters = new Bundle(); parameters.putString("Time","2:30 pm"); parameters.putString("Date","22/11/2016"); 
logger.logEvent("Parent Profile",parameters);

Answer (score 0):

You code looks just fine. Make sure you are using latest Android SDK 4.20 and you setup AndroidManifest.xml accordingly. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Take in mind that call to logEvent() will not log immediately your event, our SDK batches the events and will flush them by default after 15 secs or 100 events. More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AppEventsLogger.FlushBehavior/

In case your logging is very sparse, you may want to consider to call .flush() to explicitly flush logged event.